# Why can't I get a test resources on travis or circle CI environments?

Tags: java, junit, maven-3, travis-ci, circleci

I'm facing a very annoying issue while trying to run my project's junit tests inside a remote CI environment.

In my local machine with java 1.8.0_181 and maven 3.5.4 I don't have any problem.

I used to use the two ways bellow to get a test resource:

```
        String expected = Utils.readStream(new FileInputStream(
            "src/test/resources/testdata/fragment-subdir-absolute-path.txt"));
```

Using this I'm getting a file not found:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: fragment-subdir-absolute-path.txt (No
>   such file or directory)

And with this:

```
        String expected = Utils.readStream(new FileInputStream(getClass()
            .getResource("/testdata/fragment-subdir-absolute-path.txt")
            .getPath()));
```

In this case I'm getting a NPE:

> [ERROR] testFragmentFragmentHost  Time elapsed: 0.03 s  <<< ERROR!
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.osgi.service.indexer.impl.IndexerUnitTest.assertFragmentMatch(IndexerUnitTest.java:58)
>       at org.osgi.service.indexer.impl.IndexerUnitTest.assertFragmentMatch(IndexerUnitTest.java:71)
>       at org.osgi.service.indexer.impl.IndexerUnitTest.testFragmentFragmentHost(IndexerUnitTest.java:205)

But anyone is working inside of the remote CIs. The file is not being found.

Comment: Hi Cristiano, can you maybe share a stack trace of the exact error you are facing with?

Comment: also - even if i would suspect it does not change anything, another alternative to try would be `Utils.readString(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/testdata/fragment-subdir-absolute-path.txt"))`

Comment: Hi @MatthiasHuttar, I've updated the question. thanks

Comment: If your builds are failing on remote CI services, but not locally, I tend to think that your CI configuration is faulty. Your local machine has some artifacts that get the compilation going, and you are not instructing CI services to fetch them. Try setting up your repository from scratch on a clean system (or a Docker image).

Answer (score 1):

Well, embarrassingly, after many many hours, I found where the issue was... :)

The culprit was a copied .gitignore file that contained this:

```
# Package Files #
 target
 *.jar
 *.txt
```

Eclipse IDE adds a small interrogation icon on the uncommited files, a small repo icon to the committed ones and just remove the icon from the ignored ones. 
I just didn't pay attention to those ignored ones.

So, I changed that file to:

```
# Package Files #
target/*.jar
target/*.txt
```

and the mysterious unit tests errors have gone.

thank all for the time...